# Which hyperbolic fibered knots have monodromy with a single singularity?

Tags: knot-theory, monodromy

The figure eight-knot has pseudo-Anosov monodromy with no singularity. I have read that the (-2,3,7)-pretzel knot has pseudo-Anosov monodromy with a single 18-prong singularity on the boundary of the fiber.

My question is : do we know a class of hyperbolic fibered knots in $S^3$ whose monodromy has (at most) a single singularity on the boundary of the fiber ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fibered two-bridge knot with Seifert surface which is a plumbing of figure eight knot Seifert surfaces will have this property. One can follow the prescription of [Gabai-Kazez](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1075377) who gave a method to compute the monodromy of fibered 2-bridge knots.
These are plumbings of Hopf bands, with hyperelliptic monodromy. When the Hopf bands alternate left and right, then the monodromy will have this property (this corresponds to a plumbing of figure eight knot Seifert surfaces which is a plumbing of left and right Hopf bands). Following the example of computation in their paper, see the figures below which replace Figures 4-7 in their paper. Since the interior complementary regions of the quotient surface by a hyperelliptic involution are all bigons or orbifold monogons, the 2-fold branched cover will have only singularities at the boundary.

[image: product of Dehn twists]

[image: branched cover]

[image]

[image: invariant train track of quotient]